# JSON format to SQL Server database table data format using SSIS

Tags: arrays, json, rest, ssis, sql-server-2017

I have the following JSON response data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "metrics": {
      "budget": [
        {
          "label": "Flight Start Date",
          "value": "flight_start_date"
        },
        {
          "label": "Flight End Date",
          "value": "flight_end_date"
        }
      ],
      "engagement": [
        {
          "label": "Engaged Views (5s)",
          "value": "engagements"
        },
        {
          "label": "Engaged View Rate (5s)",
          "value": "engaged_ctr"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "messages": null,
  "status": "success",
  "status_code": 200
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to convert this JSON format and load it into an SQL 2017 table in the following format using SSIS:

```
budget label      | budget value      | engagement label       | engagement value
------------------+-------------------+------------------------+-----------------
Flight Start Date | flight_start_date | Engaged Views (5s)     | engagements
Flight End Date   | flight_end_date   | Engaged View Rate (5s) | engaged_ctr
```

I know that I can do this piecemeal with UNIONs involving budget and engagement, but I was looking for a more elegant solution that does it all at once.

Thank you!
Shawn

Comment: Sorry, don't quite follow. You have a process that generates the supplied JSON and you'd like it stored into an existing table? Dynamically create a matching table? Something else? The question then is how do I accomplish this with SSIS?

Comment: @billinkc, that is exactly right.  Sorry for my lack of clarity.  I have a process that generates the supplied JSON and would like the output stored in a table in the format (4 columns) indicated in the question.  How do I accomplish this with SSIS?

Comment: Have you identified how SSIS will receive the message? Are you going to need to write .net code to GET/POST to the service to receive this json or are these messages serialized in some other form?

Comment: There will always be a 1:1 mapping between items in `budget` to `engagement`?

Comment: @billinkc, I've already figured out how to connect to the REST API source by using the ZappySys PowerPack for SSIS.  You can assume for our purposes that you already received the JSON response as-is.  You can even assume that you are using a JSON flat file document as your SSIS source.  I am just looking at a way to be able to transform the JSON format with SSIS.  Yes, there is always a 1:1 mapping with budget and engagement.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to figure out what makes sense as I don't know what assumptions to make about what the current SSIS package can do/how it's structured. It seems [ZappySys](https://zappysys.com/blog/parse-multi-dimensional-json-array-ssis/) has a thing to smash json into a flat structure, is that not doing the trick?

Comment: @billinkc, ZappySys is only able to handle a single array. There are multi arrays in my JSON structure which have to be dealt with separately, so I was hoping to have a neater solution, but I guess doing multicast with UNIONs would probably do the trick in SSIS.  I guess I was trying to just be too fancy...